# Does an Azure Web App care if its instances are healthy/unhealthy?

Tags: azure, load-balancing, azure-web-app-service

If I deploy a web app (formerly known as an Azure WebSite) to an App Hosting Plan in Azure with a couple of instances (scale = 2) *will the load balancer in front of the instances care if any of the instances is unhealthy?*

I'm troubleshooting an issue that sometimes causes my site to return an http 503 ~50% of the time. My thinking here is that *one of two* of my instances has failed but the load balancer hasn't noticed.

If the load balancer *does care*, what does it look for? I can't find anyway to specify a ping url, for instance.

Note: this question has *nothing* to do with Traffic Manager.

Comment: That's a pretty rare scenario.  Here's a quick way to test and see if one bad instance is the problem: Scale your sites up to a larger instance for a few seconds and then back down to whatever they were originally at.  This will move your sites to a fresh set of VMs and if the problem still repros then it's an issue with the app.  The down side of this is that it destroys your repro if the problem really was with a bad instance

Comment: @ZainRizvi it's not so rare for us, which I appreciate points to an app issue. Are you saying that it's not supported?

Comment: Actually a better way to test if your issue is instance specific is to use to use ARRAffinity to specify which instance you want your request to go to . See here for more details http://blog.amitapple.com/post/2014/03/access-specific-instance/#.VV-FsnnbKic

Answer (score 3):

Yes, Azure Web Apps monitors the health of the workers by making internal requests to it and verifying that they're healthy.

However, we don't check status codes that the web app returns to user requests (like 500, etc) since that could easily be an app specific issue rather than a problem with the machine.

So the answer you're looking for is: We continuously test whether or not the instances (VMs) are healthy and take them down if they're not. However, those tests do not rely on error codes the customer's site returns

Comment: Hi @Zain- an issue I'm seeing with my app is that after deploys (and sometimes hours after a deployment) it responds _very_ slowly (minutes) before ultimately giving 503s. My theory was that the load balancer was cycling VMs or something because they were all thought to be unhealthy. I'm assuming it's an issue with my app.

Do you have any advice for where to start with issues that lead to 503s from an Azure site with multiple nodes?

Comment: Actually...it behaves very similarly to what we see if I "restart" the site--I get 403s and 503s for just about 2 minutes. Is there something we could be doing with our app start process (which would get triggered during a deployment, swap, and occasionally during normal operations) that would look like that?

Comment: 3 suggetions: 1) Take a look at your metrics and see if you can identify any obvious spikes (like memory, cpu usage, etc). 2) Switch to a single instance for your site just so that you can identify whether or not the error has anything to do with having multiple instances (I suspect it doesn't) and 3) Use the support portal to analyze your site and see if it finds any issues. You can access it at https://<yoursitename>.azurewebsites.net/support -> Analyze -> DiagnoseNow.  You can also check out the Mitigate tab where you can set up auto-mitigation rules for issues your site might encounter

Comment: Thank you for those suggestions! I did the "Diagnose Now" action and it did help me to **recreate** the problem--my site locked up for about 10 minutes (extremely slow responses, which were usually 502s or 503s). I'm assuming the diagnostics do not typically disrupt the deployed application? I ran it again and it _didn't_ disrupt things the second time (just a conincidence perhaps). Related, the support portal listed my site status as "This site is unhealthy, and may be affected due to an unknown issue with Azure App Service. Please report this."

Comment: @MichaelHaren Did you look at the reports generated when you ran Diagnose Now? Did you find anything interesting there?