# How can I set up an Azure Website with a custom health probe url?

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

I have a nasty problem locking up my Azure Website, initially running one instance. I bumped it up to two instances and I want to make sure that Azure's load balancer realizes that one instance is unhealthy and stop serving it requests until it is healthy again.

From what I understand, custom health probing is possible for Web Roles but not for Web Sites: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/jj151530.aspx

How do I let the load balancer know one of my Website instances is unhealthy?

Edit: The functionality does not exist in Azure yet but there is a [suggestion to add the capability here](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/169385-web-apps-formerly-websites/suggestions/8894002-add-url-based-probe-health-checks-to-web-apps).

Comment: Is this using traffic manager?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30403214/does-an-azure-web-app-care-if-its-instances-are-healthy-unhealthy

Comment: Nope, it isn't using Traffic Manager. And thanks for the link. It sounds like the health monitoring that is in place is in regards to the VM, and that we don't have a way to have a health probe url.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you're going to have to use Azure Traffic Manager. Azure App Service only monitors the health of the worker machines themselves, independent of the web app code running on them. If your problem is with your application, rather than the web server itself being unhealthy, this will not help you. i.e. if your app is only returning 500s, it will still appear healthy to the app service code, and have requests routed to it.

Unfortunately, out of the box, Azure App Service doesn't allow you to configure the load balancing with respect to failing requests, as load balancing only takes into account the load index of the worker servers.

See this blog for how to set up traffic manager: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/waws/archive/2015/06/01/create-an-azure-web-app-failover-solution-on-a-budget.aspx

Comment: Interesting.  I guess if the cost of spinning up a second instance within an App Service Plan is the same as having another instance in a separate App Service Plan then I like this solution.