# Does the Azure Websites Auto-scale feature include a health check?

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

I have an Azure Website set to auto-scale.

I've noticed in my logs that when a scale up happens, it *appears* (i could be making the wrong analysis) that requests are being fed to the newly started instance before it is 'healthy'.

When i say 'healthy' - i mean my app takes around 30 seconds to start up.

I would *hope* that the internal load balancer waits for a HTTP 200 (OK) to be returned by the instance before feeding requests to it, but doesn't feel like this is the case?

Can someone confirm the scale out semantics and point to some articles please?

Thanks

Comment: As Zain Rizvi replied in this [issue](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30403214/does-an-azure-web-app-care-if-its-instances-are-healthy-unhealthy), Azure Web Apps monitors the health of the workers by making internal requests to it and verifying that they're healthy. However, Azure doesn't check status codes that the web app returns to user requests (like 500, etc) since that could easily be an app specific issue rather than a problem with the machine.

Comment: @Bruce - MSFT: issue doesn't state _what_ the health checks are? If it doesn't check status codes, what _does_ it check? If the IIS wp is running? Is it possible requests could be sent to an instance that is still starting up (eg Global asax warmup)

Answer (score 2):

The best way to solve this is to use app init. This will prevent traffic from being routed to the app until it is "warmed up".

You can read about it here --> http://ruslany.net/2015/09/how-to-warm-up-azure-web-app-during-deployment-slots-swap/

This applies to both scale operations as well as swap.

Comment: That's cool! Does that article confirm that the load balancer does indeed a) do a HTTP request to the root directory, and b) _wait_ for a 200 (OK)? Because if that's the case - i don't _need_ this feature. The root folder hit takes 30 seconds.. that's what i want to make sure Azure waits for. So there is no other route/url to warm up?

Comment: using the method described in the article prevents App Service from routing traffic to the specific instance until the app initialization completes. That way if your app takes 30 seconds or 10 minutes to be ready for traffic, it doesn't matter, traffic will only be routed to it once its ready.

Comment: There's an unanswered question on the site you linked: if you supply the host name in the App Initialization configuration like the article describles, how can you be sure it warms up the correct instance in a multi-instance setup (e.g. autoscaling).

Comment: this all happens internally on the instance where the the app gets assigned, so the fact the instance is assigned the app triggers the logic